# Build a grid search for tuning hyperparameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, hyperparameters

I need to build a grid search for tuning hyperparameters. Supose a two ranges: `lambda = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]` and `sigma = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]`. How can I build a custom grid search? I have created a custom SVM class, called `CustomSVM()`, with `fit()`, `predict()` and `score()` methods. I would like to make a search grid on that class to see which parameters are the best suited.

I have thought

```
for x in lambda:
   for y in sigma: 
      ...
```

but I am not sure how to coninue.

Comment: you need to provide a minimal sample code that we can copy and paste it into a single file and run it

Comment: @TuanTran I have created a little code to show how I thought the problem. Does it help? I am just not sure how to buid that grid search to pick up the best sigma and lambda for my `CustomSVM()`

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn has a grid search class, could you use [this?](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

parameters = {
            'lambda': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1], 
            'sigma': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]}

svm_gs = GridSearchCV(customSVM, parameters)
svm_gs.fit(your.data, your.target)
```

I don't see why your `for loop` solution wouldn't work as well; you can reference the GridSearchCV docs for ideas.

Comment: I know that, but I can't use GridSearchCV

Comment: @David What is the reason for not using GridSearchCV? The showed solution is clean and pythonic (sklearnish) way to achieve your goals.